# External JS not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've got a main JS script which looks something like this..

```
;(function ($) {

<main javascript>

}(jQuery));
```

I've just created my own external library script which looks like this..

```
;(function ($) {

var myClass = function() {
    <code>
};

}(jQuery));
```

What I want to do is pass my external library into the main JS script, to look something like this:

```
;(function ($, myClass) {

<main javascript>

}(jQuery, myClass));
```

However it says that myClass is undefined. How do I go about defining it?

(In terms of how I'm inserting the code it's using register/enqueue script with Wordpress. Both files are "active" so if I was to throw an alert into them both then they'd both get fired off, I'm just struggling with linking the two together so that I can use the scripts inside myClass whilst within my main JS file).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myClass` is defined within the scope of

```
(function ($) {
  ...
}(jQuery));
```

so unless the code in that library does

```
this.myClass = myClass;
```

or something else to explicitly export it into the global scope then there is no way to reference it from your main script.

---

[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript) has a lot of discussion on the pros & cons of various ways of exposing an interface to other code in JavaScript.

Comment: @user1157885, please see my edit that includes links to relevant discussions.